# There are exist analog of input type="date" in spring tags?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp

It really to rewrite so code using spring style?

```
<input type="date"  name="date" value="<fmt:formatDate value="${vacancy.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>">
```

Comment: idea no mean what you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${vacancy.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" var="vacancyDate"/>
<form:input path="date" value="${vacancyDate}"/>
```

You can't use tags like this:

```
value="<fmt:formatDate value="${vacancy.date}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>"
```

You are trying to use it directly in the `value` attribute. You need to declare it first as I showed above with the variable, in this case: `var="vacancyDate"` which will be available in the page scope. And then pass this value using: `${vacancyDate}`.

**EDIT:**

According to your comment, what you need is [jQuery UI datapicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). Include jQuery UI into your project and give your field some ID.

```
<form:input id="idDateField" path="date"/>
```

And add javascript to initialize your datapicker:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          $('#idDateField').datepicker();
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: I want to see nice calendar, but I saw simple text input